# Pass SSOTokenID as set-cookie value in OpenAM

Tags: http, cookies, openam

I'm using openam OAuth/OpenID for user authentication. As mentioned in the documentations, I could get SSOTokenID as a JSON object by making following HTTP request.

```
curl -X POST -H "X-OpenAM-Username: demo" -H "X-OpenAM-Password: changeit" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '' -k -v https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/json/authenticate?realm=/
```

Instead of that, I want to get SSOTokenID as the Set-Cookie header value of the HTTP response. Are there anyway that i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only using an authentication module that accepts a NameCallback and PasswordCallback (as you used in your example), then you can just use the legacy UI  zero-page login , you need to disable XUI though

Using your example

```
curl -X POST  -d 'IDToken1=demo&IDToken2=changeit' -k -v https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/UI/Login?realm=/
```